# Why does the event handler toggle the class name just at the first item element but not for the rest?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, toggle, accordion

I see the class being actively added in the console for the first element, but only for the first element. The event listener is tied to an svg button. Class 'open' turns 'hidden-block' display into display: block; in the item container

```js
const faqDropDown = document.querySelector(".accordion-icon");
const faqContainer = document.querySelector(".item");

faqDropDown.addEventListener("click", function() {
  faqContainer.classList.toggle("open");
});
```

```css
.item { margin-bottom: 10px; }
p { margin: 0; }
svg { width 1em; height: 1em; margin: 10px; }
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <p class="number">01</p>
  <p class="text">lorem ipsum ist?</p>
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    class="accordion-icon"
    fill="none"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    stroke="currentColor"
  >
    <path
      stroke-linecap="round"
      stroke-linejoin="round"
      stroke-width="2"
      d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"
    />
  </svg>

  <div class="hidden-box">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
      Et, tempore repudiandae. Minima, cupiditate totam nihil
      laborum rem sit, est, ea et quaerat hic accusantium quos.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <p class="number">02</p>
  <p class="text">lorem ipsum ist?</p>
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    class="accordion-icon"
    fill="none"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    stroke="currentColor"
  >
    <path
      stroke-linecap="round"
      stroke-linejoin="round"
      stroke-width="2"
      d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"
    />
  </svg>

  <div class="hidden-box">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
      Et, tempore repudiandae. Minima, cupiditate totam nihil
      laborum rem sit, est, ea et quaerat hic accusantium quos.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP needs a state handling across all of an accordion's items. Thus, as for the provided example, an event handler has to be registered for every item's svg icon.

The handler then not only needs to take care of an item's toggle state but also needs to detect and process the case of closing all other items ...

```js
function handleAccordionItemStates({ currentTarget }) {
  const currentItem = currentTarget.closest('.item');
  const currentAccordion = currentItem.closest('.accordion');

  const isCloseOthers = !currentItem.classList.contains('open');
  if (isCloseOthers) {

    currentAccordion
      .querySelectorAll('.item')
      .forEach(item => {
        if (item !== currentItem) {
          item.classList.remove('open');
        }
      });
  }
  currentItem.classList.toggle('open');
}

function init() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('.accordion-icon')
    .forEach(elmNode =>
      elmNode.addEventListener('click', handleAccordionItemStates)
    );
}
init();
```

```css
p { margin: 0; }
svg {
  width 1em;
  height: 1em;
  transition: transform .3s ease-in;
}

.item { margin-bottom: 10px; }
.item p { float: left; margin-right: 10px; }
.item svg { float: right; margin-right: 50px; }

.hidden-box {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 5px;
  transition: max-height .6s ease-in-out;
  max-height: 0;
}
.item.open .hidden-box { max-height: 900px; }
.item.open svg { transform: rotate(180deg); }
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="item">
    <p class="number">01</p>
    <p class="text">lorem ipsum</p>
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      class="accordion-icon"
      fill="none"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      stroke="currentColor"
    >
      <path
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        stroke-width="2"
        d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"
      />
    </svg>

    <div class="hidden-box">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et,
        tempore repudiandae. Minima, cupiditate totam nihil laborum rem sit,
        est, ea et quaerat hic accusantium quos.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <p class="number">02</p>
    <p class="text">accusantium quos</p>
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      class="accordion-icon"
      fill="none"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      stroke="currentColor"
    >
      <path
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        stroke-width="2"
        d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"
      />
    </svg>

    <div class="hidden-box">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et,
        tempore repudiandae. Minima, cupiditate totam nihil laborum rem sit,
        est, ea et quaerat hic accusantium quos.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <p class="number">03</p>
    <p class="text">cupiditate totam</p>
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      class="accordion-icon"
      fill="none"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      stroke="currentColor"
    >
      <path
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        stroke-width="2"
        d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"
      />
    </svg>

    <div class="hidden-box">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et,
        tempore repudiandae. Minima, cupiditate totam nihil laborum rem sit,
        est, ea et quaerat hic accusantium quos.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you are using `querySelector` which will return the first object that it encounters, this means that it will return only the first item that is `.item`.

In order to apply some change to multiple items with a class  (I think you have multiple `class="item"`) you need to use `querySelectorAll`, which will return an array of nodes that have the class `item`.

below I left you an example of how to use `querySelectorAll` and then loop over each node and then apply the change that you want.

note: if you look at the code the html was made by me just to show it works (it changes all the items to red). the javascript part is the one that changed to do the correct change over all the items. just copy paste it on your code and it should work.

```js
const faqDropDown = document.querySelector(".accordion-icon");
const faqContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".item");

faqDropDown.addEventListener("click", function() {
  faqContainers.forEach(faqContainer => {
    faqContainer.classList.toggle("open");
  })
});
```

```css
.open {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion-icon">
toggle open
</button>

<div class="item">
  item1
</div>

<div class="item">
  item2
</div>

<div class="item">
  item3
</div>

<div class="item">
  item4
</div>
```

Comment: Similar to what I am looking for! However, I want it to only open and close up the dropdown I click on. How would I go about that?